# How to compare timestamps between 2 time points that are in conflict

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have an appointments table. I need to check that no date between `validfrom` and `validuntil` conflict with another record that has a date that might be partially or fully in between the date of another record.

E.g. the picture below, record 2's date 08.02.2019 - 05.02.2019 is in conflict with record 3's date 03.02.2019 - 09.02.2019, because day 08.02.2019 and 09.02.2017 are in the range of the 3rd record.

[image]

How would I be able to produce a table of results that shows me any appointments that are in conflict for each staff member?

In other words I want this:

[image]

Here is the basic query gist:

```
select sa.staffid,sa.appointmentid,a.validfrom,a.validuntil 
from staffappointment sa
join staff s on s.id = sa.staffid
join appointment a on a.id = sa.appointmentid
where .....
```

Comment: Do you want to prevent inserting rows like that, or do you just want a query that shows those rows?

Comment: just show those 2 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use a self join and check for overlaps:

```
SELECT sa1.staffid, sa1.appointmentid, a1.validfrom, a1.validuntil
FROM staffappointment AS sa1
   JOIN appointment a1 ON a1.id = sa1.appointmentid
   JOIN staffappointment AS sa2
      ON sa1.staffid = sa2.staffid AND sa1.appointmentid <> sa2.appointmentid
   JOIN appointment a2 ON a2.id = sa2.appointmentid
WHERE tstzrange(a1.validfrom, a1.validuntil) && tstzrange(a2.validfrom, a2.validuntil);
```